# How to overlay thumbnail of photo just taken at the bottom of the camera view in iOS?

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a view controller with image picker, it takes one photo and moves on to the next screen for user's description input.  Now I'm trying to allow the user to take multiple photos in the same view controller such that after each photo snap, a thumbnail appears at the bottom in a list view style similar to how eBay iOS app does.  What is the standard way to go about implementing this feature?  Right now, I'm thinking using overlay at the bottom and populating the list with thumbnails.  Are there any libraries that can help me do this?  I've searched stackflow for an answer, but I didn't see any question that dealt with this programming problem.  Thanks in advance for your help.